# onchange javascript and adding elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with javascript while trying to add a textfield to my form with "onchange", this is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="formdemo">

</form>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Volvo">33
  <option value="1">1
  <option value="Audi">Audi
  <option value="BMW">BMW
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo
</select>



<script>
function myFunction() {

   if (document.getElementById("mySelect").value == "1") {
            document.getElementById("formdemo").innerHTML = "   First name: <input type = "text" name ="firstname">"
        }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I want to generate a text field when the user chose "1", but The problem is that when I choose the "1" value the text field does not appear.

But when I remove the "input type" code from javascript, code looks like this:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

   if (document.getElementById("mySelect").value == "1") {
            document.getElementById("formdemo").innerHTML = "   First name:"
        }
}
</script>
```

It works!!, it shows the "First name:" to site.
Is this method that I am using just for strings or just for adding paragraphs and I should use another method to add forms, or I am using wrong syntax?

Thank you for reading this, have a good day.

Comment: `"   First name: <input type = "text" name ="firstname">"` should be `"   First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\">";`

Comment: You need to fix your JS syntax errors - if you'd bothered to even glance at your browser's debug console, you'd see why this code won't ever run as-is.

Comment: @Lashane , thanks, it works, keep going.

Comment: i tried that earlier, but I forgot to add ";"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just in the innterHTML your have a little mistake.

```
document.getElementById("formdemo").innerHTML = "   First name: <input type = "text" name ="firstname">"
```

and should be like

```
document.getElementById("formdemo").innerHTML = "   First name: <input type='text' name='firstname'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong in String input :

```
<form id="formdemo">

</form>

<p>Select a new car from the list.</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {

   if (document.getElementById("mySelect").value == "1") {
            document.getElementById("formdemo").innerHTML = 
            "First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\">";
        }
}
</script>
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="Volvo">33</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
</select>
```

the input should be like `"First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\">";`

here is  a fiddle :> [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lm4v4bd9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way

```
var input = document.createElement("textarea");
div.appendChild(input);
```